# build eclipse c++ projects from command line, without eclipse?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, build

I'm using Eclipse to develop my c++ application, it contains several dependent projects.
I compile my application from Eclipse IDE just fine on development machine.

I'm using minimal RHEL install on production machine, no UI. I do not want to use Eclipse on production machine.

How to make it possible to build Eclipse c++ projects on machine without UI and without Eclipse? (should I use make, ant or something like this?)

upd:

I've found that for each project I can find makefile in 'Release' folder. But I should execute "make clean" and then "make all" for each project in right order. When in Eclipse I execute "Project - Clean" and then "Project - Build All" Eclipse knows right order to build. What command should I execute to force build all projects in right order? (or there are no such command and I should write the script to build all projects in right order myself)

Comment: Yes, you could use make..

Comment: where should I add includes/compile options etc.? i expect to add this in one point, and then it should be used everywhere - in make scripts and in Eclipse IDE. (so I do not want to "synchronize" Eclipse with make). Now I add this stuff in Eclipse Properties page which is unaccessible in make?

Comment: Well, you would have to create a makefile where you define variables for include paths, for options, for libraries and then pass them to the compilation command, which should be g++

Comment: can I somehow generate makefiles from Eclipse projects settings, and then substitute Eclipse projects settings with makefiles generated?

Comment: Maybe you could do that, I have no idea

Comment: It is worth learning how to build a `Makefile` if you are serious about programming. It's a basic tool.

Comment: @Galik Java programmers never cared too much about low level utilities, IDEs always did the job for them :D

Comment: @Mansuro `C++` isn't `Java` but when I was a `Java` programmer we did a lot of hand crafted `Ant` shenanigans in addition to using makefiles for various stuff. The problem with using an `IDE` for the build is you can not build it in a different `IDE` without recreating the project. And if you can't use an `IDE` then what?

Comment: i've found that Eclipse creates makefile for each project in "Release"/"Debug" folders. so likely it must be quite easy to compile using these generated makefiles. so I should keep using Properties page, and Eclipse creates makefiles for me.